# How to reduce multiple condition with strings - python

Tags: python, if-statement

How can i reduce this condition ?

`item` is always a string

```
for item in list_of_items:
    if ('beans' in item or 'apple' in item or 'eggs' in item or 'banana' in item) and ('elephant' not in item) or 'chicken' not in item:
                print(item)
```

I mean can I somehow give list of words to check every possibility?

Comment: `set(list_of_items).intersection({'beans', 'apple', 'eggs', 'banana'})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `any` with a generator or list comprehension:

```
if any(word in item for word in ['apple', 'beans', 'eggs', 'banana', 'elephant', 'chicken')):
```

Comment: Except a missing `]`

Answer (score 1):

Using `list-comprehension`:

```
good_items = ['beans','apple','eggs','banana', 'elephant', 'chicken']
list_of_items = ['apple', 'grapes', 'elephant', 'chicken']

print([x for x in list_of_items if x in good_items and x not in ['elephant', 'chicken']])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['apple']
```

Comment: Note the parentheses. The condition is `('elephant' not in item) or 'chicken' not in item` not `('elephant' not in item or 'chicken' not in item)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` for the first part.

However the second part cannot be reduced

```
if any(w in item for w in ('beans', 'apple', 'eggs', 'banana')) and ('elephant' not in item) or 'chicken' not in item:
```

Not useful for your case but you should be aware that all is also useful.

You can reduce this `if 'a' not in item and 'b' not in item` to `if all(w not in item for w in ('a', 'b')`